# Tiny C Compiler (TCC) and winsock?

Tags: c, sockets, winsock, tcc

Can I use a socket library from TCC? I can't find any reference to winsock or sys/socket.h in the include directory.

If i remember correctly, winsock was part of the windows platform SDK (?) If so can I link that with TCC?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [Tinycc-devel mailing list](http://www.mail-archive.com/tinycc-devel@nongnu.org/msg02059.html)

you should give this a try:

```
tiny_impdef winsock.dll -o winsock.def
tcc yourcode.c  winsock.def -o yourcode.exe
```

Comment: Found wsock32.h on google code search. It included a few others that were easily found. Worked like a charm, cheers

Comment: @tm1rbrt how do you know it worked like a charm if you got the file from somewhere rather than use the method in the answer? btw tcc asks for winsock.h  maybe renaming wsock32.h to winsock.h works If so you could put that in your own answer. And it requires common.h which isn't in there.

Answer (score 8):

1. Use `tiny_impdef.exe` to export definitions from the DLL file using the command line:
   `tiny_impdef.exe wsock32.dll -o .\lib\wsock32.def`
2. You will also need the header files for your source code to include them. MinGW's ones (such as `winsock2.h`, `ws2tcpip.h`, `ws2spi.h`...) can be reused with TCC.
   The MinGW compiler can be downloaded from **[here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/)**. Just copy the headers you need from MinGW's `include` directory to TCC's `include\winapi` directory.
3. At compilation time, you will need to tell the compiler you are using the Windows socket library:
   `tcc.exe path\to\code.c -lwsock32 -o path\to\program.exe`

Comment: C:\Users\compile\Desktop\tcc>tcc.exe code.c -lwsock32 -o program.exe
In file included from code.c:6:
c:/users/compile/desktop/tcc/include/winapi/winsock2.h:10: error: include file '_mingw_unicode.h' not found

Comment: Used mingw-w64-v7.0.0: https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/ And 
tcc-0.9.27-win64-bin.zip http://download.savannah.gnu.org/releases/tinycc/

Comment: mingw-w64-v7.0.0.zip\mingw-w64-headers\crt folder does contain _mingw_unicode.h

Comment: However dropping all the headers from mingw-w64-v7.0.0.zip\mingw-w64-headers\crt to the tcc\include does not resolve the problem and continually shows different error:

Comment: C:\Users\compile\Desktop\tcc>tcc.exe code.c -lwsock32 -o program.exe
In file included from code.c:5:
In file included from c:/users/compile/desktop/tcc/include/stdio.h:9:
In file included from c:/users/compile/desktop/tcc/include/crtdefs.h:10:
In file included from c:/users/compile/desktop/tcc/include/corecrt.h:10:
In file included from c:/users/compile/desktop/tcc/include/_mingw.h:27:
c:/users/compile/desktop/tcc/include/stddef.h:18: error: ';' expected (got "extern")

Comment: It seems that latest TCC compiler compiled from git repository sources code does work properly with winsocks and some other libraries.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't used TCC nor used Windows since 2013...

Answer (score 1):

```
tiny_impdef winsock.dll
```

copy winsock.def to lib/

run:

```
tcc -lwinsock yourcode.c -o yourcode.exe
```