# tiny c compiler use GetUserName

Tags: c, winapi, tcc

I use the Tiny C Compiler and I want to use `GetUserName` from
the WinAPI. My problem is, I don't know how to link to `advapi32.dll`

I get an error from tcc:

```
undefined symbol '_GetUserNameA@8'
```

Comment: Have you looked in tcc-win32.txt?

Comment: so, is your question answered? @Martin Broadhurst, either of you two should add that as answer if so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I explained how to create a .def file from a dll and how to compile and link  with tcc here:
 [Tiny C Compiler (TCC) and winsock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4069770/tiny-c-compiler-tcc-and-winsock/4070300#4070300)