# TCC and winsock.h

Tags: c, sockets, tcc

I have already read [Tiny C Compiler (TCC) and winsock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4069770/tiny-c-compiler-tcc-and-winsock), but I still can't compile sockets with TCC, because when I try

```
 tiny_impdef winsock.dll -o winsock.def
```

tiny_impdef responds:

```
Not a PE file: C:\WINDOWS\system32\winsock.dll
```

So how can I do to compile properly a program that use sockets? Any help will be appreciated

Comment: I gave the answer to this question on this post:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4069770/tiny-c-compiler-tcc-and-winsock/9351171#9351171

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that you have a 64 bit machine and `TCC` is 32 bit. In that situation `C:\WINDOWS\system32\winsock.dll` is the 64 bit version of winsock. Try it this way:

```
tiny_impdef C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\winsock.dll -o winsock.def
```

to pick up winsock from the 32 bit system directory.

Comment: You are possibly aiming too high, winsock.dll was the 16-bit version of ws2_32.dll.  So was tcc.exe.   A bits/4 problem.  We need a "asked 15 years too late" close reason at SO, please vote along.

Comment: @hans I think there are >16 bit winsock.dlls in existance. Also tcc can target 32 and 64 bit code.

Comment: @hans This is Tiny C not Turbo C. No I never used either. As you must know by now I'm not really one for languages with braces.  ;-)

Comment: I do have an active memory of it from Byte magazine.  Not sure what it takes to extinguish it, you're not helping :)

Comment: @Hans Passant Thank you! Worked with ws2_32.dll.And to clear doubts: My OS is WinXP 32 bits service pack 2, and my computer is an Pentium 4 HT

Comment: Well, that was a drive-by accident.  Don't hesitate to post it and accept it as an answer.  Feel free to embellish.