# Error when including Windows.h with TCC

Tags: windows, tcc

What I really wanted to do was to include Ws2tcpip, so I followed the instructions in the answers from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4069770/tiny-c-compiler-tcc-and-winsock) thread, copied MinGW's include files to \tcc\include\winapi\ and created a library from wsock2.dll. But the problem I get now is when I include Windows.h.

```
....\tcc\include\winapi\winnt.h|3819|error: declaration list expected|
```

which is

```
typedef __AW(OSVERSIONINFO) OSVERSIONINFO,*POSVERSIONINFO,*LPOSVERSIONINFO;
```

So how do I get the winapi to work with tcc?

Thanks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4069770/tiny-c-compiler-tcc-and-winsock

Comment: What made you think that these headers can be copied between compilers and just work?

Comment: @sashoalm yes I've seen it. The post that Mathieu Rodic posted said that you simply could use the MinGW's headers with TCC.