# C - tcc finds error in commdlg.h?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, tcc

I'm attempting to write a C program incorporating OPENFILENAME and of course I need the header file.  So, following the instructions provided with tcc, I downloaded the header files MinGW uses for the Win32 API (and the library files) and put them in the appropriate directories as instructed.  However, when I come to compile the program, I get the following error:

```
In file included from sw1.c:2:
c:/prg/tcc/include/winapi/commdlg.h:503: declaration list expected
```

This seems rather odd, given it's a standard header.  So, I look up the line and it's `typedef __AW(CHOOSECOLOR) CHOOSECOLOR,*LPCHOOSECOLOR;`, which doesn't look very valid to me but then I'm not really a C expert and I've mainly been writing in Linux.  I have no idea why it's going wrong though and no knowledge of how to fix it?  Is it a bug in tcc?

As evidence that this should be possible, here is the appropriate passage from the tcc readme:

> Header Files:
>
> ---
>
> The system header files (except _mingw.h) are from the MinGW
>      distribution:
>
> http://www.mingw.org/
>
> From the windows headers, only a minimal set is included.  If you need
>      more,  get MinGW's "w32api" package.

I understand that this question is similar to [Error when including Windows.h with TCC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23541981/error-when-including-windows-h-with-tcc) but my "windows.h" file *does* work - it's just this that doesn't.

Does anyone know how to solve this?  I'm really at a loose end!

Comment: You might want to look for that line causes the error in the question you linked in your working version of `winnt.h` file and see if it has be changed to work with tcc.

Comment: When you look at the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646839.aspx) it tells you which file declares a symbol, and which header file to include. Don't include *Commdlg.h*, include *Windows.h* instead.

Comment: @IInspectable I included windows.h _as well_.  If I comment out the `#include <commdlg.h>`, I get the error: `sw1.c:50: 'OPENFILENAME' undeclared`.  It _needs_ the header file, but won't compile with it!